# Extract the perpendicular point with another point angle

Tags: image, matlab, extract, point, angle

If there is a known point in the picture, this point has a certain angle also known, how can I find the four surrounding points to cut a polygon where one of these points or path between the surrounding points is perpendicular to the point angle?

The distance between the origin point and the surrounding points is constant and assume 8 pixels.

As shown in the linked picture:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myYaR.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the point's angle? Is this calculated elsewhere? You can't have an angle with just one point.